# Example of an increasing non-nonnegative sequence violating conclusion of monotone convergence theorem in space of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

With Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x) \equiv -\frac{1}{n}$ is a good example which doesn't coincide with MCT.

However, I couldn't find another example when the measure is finite.

Could anyone give an example which MCT can't apply in finite measure space?

Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused. Since the MCT is a theorem, it can't have counterexamples. Are you looking for examples where just one of the assumptions of the MCT fails, together with the conclusion?

Comment: Yes, right. The title, in fact, doesn't make sense rigorously. Thanks!

Comment: I allowed myself to improve(?) the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is
$$
(0,1)\to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto -1/(nx)
$$
what you are looking for?

Comment: I suspect, but am far from sure, that $x\mapsto -1/(xn)$ is more along the lines of what the OP wants.

Comment: Oooops, I was too fast in typing :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, PhoemueX and HaraldHanche-Olsen.